# how to know what crontab is going to do

Tags: cron, debian-squeeze

Somehow the stuff i wrote in the crontab is now working as i wish.
To be more exactly, i think it is not executing my commands.
So now i would like to know if there is a way to get a plan what crontab, where it describes what he's going to do for today.
But not by reading the **/etc/crontab** by myself, i would like to say to cron: *give me a report of your plan for today*
So i can see if i'm just to retarded to load the stuff i write into his plan or if i have to look somewhere other for the reason.

Of corse, if there is a better practice, you have my attention!

When i do the commands by myself there is no problemo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there was a "dry run" option in cron, but couldn't find it. What I typically do is redirect output to a specific file, i.e.:

```
/usr/local/bin/mycommand &>/var/log/mycommand.log
```

By default, cron will send a mail with the output. Have you checked those? I know this doesn't answer your question, but you might consider this to check if your command runs fine.

Comment: i'm going to make some tests with the log, that is indeed a good way to see whats going on.
are you sure its **&>** and not **>>**

Comment: `&>` should be equivalent to `2>&1 >` (i.e. redirecting stderr to stdout) but IIRC not all shells support this.

Answer (score 2):

Try CronBuddy. Put in your crontab timing values and get back a list of run times. (www.CronBuddy.com)

Comment: domain is not available

Comment: CronBuddy.com seems to be back with us.